# How to place my Icon next to my <a> tag text

Tags: css

I have an imported icon in which I am including in my  tag. However, I am struggling to get the icon next to the text that is in my  tag. The icon (Download2), instead, appears above the text. Using CSS, how can I get the icon evenly aligned horizontally with my text ("Download")?

```
<a className={styles.downloadText} href={downloadUrl} target='_blank' download><Download2 color={BASE_COLOR} size='18' />Download</a>
```

Also, can anyone tell me how to add spacing between the icon and the text, without using  ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I've created a codepen to show you an example: https://codepen.io/Salaah01/pen/RwVyBOx

Comment: This works to center the text underneath the icon but I am trying to get the text next to the icon evenly. Changing "column" to row" did fix this, though. Thanks